# Boolean slicing by comparing one to many columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can i compare a column to all other columns and obtain a boolean series to slice the dataframe by using i loc?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.random.normal(1,10,(10,1))
b = np.random.normal(1,5,(10,1))
c = np.random.normal(1,5,(10,1))
d = np.random.normal(1,5,(10,1))

e = np.append(a,b, axis = 1)
e = np.append(e,c, axis = 1)
e = np.append(e,d, axis = 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = e, columns=['a','b','c','d'])



          a         b          c          d
0   4.043832 -1.672865  -0.401864   3.073481
1   4.828796 -0.830688   3.652347  -1.780346
2  13.055145  5.730707  -2.305093  -4.566279
3   6.589498 -0.525029  -1.077942  -3.850963
4   5.273932 -1.003112   0.393002  -0.415573
5  -7.872004 -2.506250   1.725281   6.676886
6  -4.797119  6.448990   0.254142  -7.374601
7   8.610763  8.075350  13.043584  12.768633
8 -10.871154  2.152322   2.093089  11.570059
9 -22.148239  1.493870   3.649696   2.455621

df.loc[df.a > df.b]
```

Will give the desired result, but only for a 1:1 comparison

```
        a         b          c          d
0   4.043832 -1.672865  -0.401864   3.073481
1   4.828796 -0.830688   3.652347  -1.780346
2  13.055145  5.730707  -2.305093  -4.566279
3   6.589498 -0.525029  -1.077942  -3.850963
4   5.273932 -1.003112   0.393002  -0.415573
7   8.610763  8.075350  13.043584  12.768633
```

My Approach was like this:

```
S = ['b','c','d']

(df.a > df[S]).any(axis = 1)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

But unfortunately, the series is somehow False for all rows. How can i solve this Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lt`

```
df[S].lt(df.a,0).any(axis=1)
Out[808]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using this for a mask, you could simply add another axis to the underlying ndarray to allow for broadcasting. This should be somewhat faster, depending on the size of your DataFrame.

```
(df[S].values < df.a.values[:,None]).any(1)
```